# identify system is single boot or dual boot in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos7

I used lsblk -f to find out what filesystem my partitions are using.
do FSTYPE can help to identify boot info. like my system is single boot or dual boot?

```
$ sudo lsblk -f

NAME        FSTYPE LABEL      MOUNTPOINT
sda                           
├─sda1      ntfs   OS         
├─sda2      ntfs   Data       
├─sda3                        
├─sda5      ext4              /
└─sda6      swap              [SWAP]
```

Comment: Your system is dualboot - you have windows installed too. Nasty.

Comment: ok so this command is sufficient to identify ? @NieDzejkob

Comment: I can see that there are two partitions with a windows-specific filesystem, so this is probably right. Why do you want to identify this?

Comment: I have a many systems so i need to find out whether my system is single boot or dual boot ......Thanks @NieDzejkob